# Add an element outside a ConstraintLayout for my adapter

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, layout

I'm trying to display cool dot when I want to notify new items. When i set negative margin or translation, the dot is cut, theses littles ilustration will make things a lot clearer:

What i want :

[image]

What I get :

[image]

Here's my layout xml :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="240dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

    android:elevation="1dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_element_list"
    android:foreground="@drawable/effect_ripple"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/file_img"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="210dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_pdf"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/file_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:paddingStart="20sp"
        android:paddingEnd="20sp"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="teeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeest"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/dark_grey"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/file_img" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/file_new"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_newfile"
        android:translationY="-22dp"
        android:translationX="22dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Someone have an idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this with your parameter's

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/profileCard"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        app:cardElevation="4dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="false">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="210dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="teeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeest"
                android:textColor="#727272"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/userImageProfile"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/profileCard"
        android:layout_marginEnd="-15dp"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        app:tint="@color/black" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

On the *ConstraintLayout*, set

```
android:clipChildren="false"
```

This will allow the *ImageView* to draw outside the *ConstraintLayout*.  See the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup#attr_android:clipChildren).

Answer (score 1):

If you use `padding` on the layout instead of `layout_margin`, and set `clipToPadding` as `false`, things will be able to draw within the padding area. Margin is really for required space *outside* of the `View`, padding is space *inside* it (where it draws its contents)